# If the very first codon of an mRNA strand is a start codon (ie, AUG) does no 5' UTR exist?

Tags: amino-acids, translation, codon

Apologies if this is too basic of a question, but from what I've learned all mature mRNA strands have both a 5' and 3' UTR. Normally this is just because the start codon has not appeared yet. However, I was given a complete strand of mRNA where the very first sequence was the AUG codon. Does the translation skip this codon to form a UTR and wait for the second, or does it immediately start translating with no UTR?

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Please take the time to finish the [Tour. You write “I was given”. By whom? What was it — a real mRNA or just something invented for a student question?  I suspect the latter. But you need to provide us with this context if we are to help you. There are questions about the initiation of eukaryotic (I assume it was this — it’s important to know) protein synthesis on this site. You should check them out. I wonder whether your question should be “are there eukaryotic mRNAs without a 5’ UTR?” Personally I doubt it, but I may be wrong.

Comment: It would be a student problem, yes. 
The entire (very small) mRNA sequence encoded by the human XAM gene is given
below. The stop codon is capitalized.
5’-augucccauccuuuucaccaggaugggagagguugcuucccucccacauccggcaugcgcauuaUAAaagaugauaauauaaag-3’

The problem looks like this, and as it starts with AUG, I am wondering whether to skip that one to leave a 5' UTR. I apologize for the lack of clarity.

Comment: @FK18 There are a few ways of dealing with this - You could look up the gene and decide for yourself; you could BLAST the sequences and various translations and see what turns up.

Comment: If it is a student problem then it is just on interpreting the genetic code. I cannot find a human XAM gene and suspect it is entirely fictitious. In any case there can be no justification for missing the first AUG. Real bacterial mRNAs always have at least a ribosomal binding sequence preceding a start AUG, and eukaryotic mRNAs almost always have a cap sequence at the 5' end, where the ribosome binds and scans along to either the first AUG (generally) or a subsequent one. But clearly the question is not about this. This is often the problem with this type of contrived problem.